# Compile-Time Check for 32/64-bit Binary Compatibility of Structures?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ program that, for good reason(1), requires a binary data format stored on disk.  Composing that data are arbitrary `struct` entries.

My program has both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and it's possible that the binary data file could be written by one and read by another.  This means that the fields of the stored structures must be of types with predictable sizes and alignments so that the resulting layout is identical for both natural word sizes.

I'm concerned that a future maintainer might accidentally violate this by adding an `int` without really thinking or having something like a single `uint32_t` followed immediately by a `uint64_t`.

*Is there any way to do a compile-time check* (i.e. `static_assert`) *that a structure will be laid out identically on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems?  What about a run-time check if the former isn't possible?*

Conceptually, I think it would be something like this:

```
for (every field):
  static_assert: sizeof_32(field) == sizeof_64(field)
  static_assert: offset_of(next_field) == offset_of(field) + sizeof(field)
```

Or more simply:

```
static_assert: sizeof_32(struct) == sizeof_64(struct)
```

Given that the program is being compiled for both bit sizes, it would technically be okay to assert on only one architecture since that would still expose the problem.

It's also okay if the structures being checked are somewhat restricted (such as requiring explicit padding fields) so long as it can be guaranteed correct.

---

1. The file is memory-mapped and all reads/writes are random-access
   through pointers.  Serialization is not an option.

Comment: What about reading the binary file in item by item, and putting them in the struct, without assuming the binary file matches your structs byte-for-byte?

Comment: Why don't you instead use types with a specific number of bits like `int32_t` and such? That way you will never have any problem.

Comment: The answer is to use a real serialization library like [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) instead of writing raw structs to disk.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, it is so NOT the answer in many cases.

Comment: It sounds like you're planning on writing and reading these structs to and from files all at once, using `fwrite` and the like.  That's a popular technique, but it's a portability nightmare; you're tying your file format to the way your compiler happens to lay out structs.  If instead you write and read things a field at a time, with control over the on-disk format independent of the in-memory representation, you don't have to worry about 32 vs. 64 bit, or padding, or endianness, or all the other things you'll have to try to control if you read and write whole structs.

Comment: No, if this was a problem the BITMAPS would never be possible and many other binary files too. Just ensure the structure is "packed" (ie. it has no padding), choose endianess (little endian should be good) and use specific size fields.

Comment: Doubt it is possible. 32bit compilation knows nothing of 64bit compilation and vice versa. You have to bite the bullet - doing packed struct serialization requires programmers discipline. If the discipline is not there, you can't serialize in packed struct. Pretty philosophical thing.

Comment: @SteveSummit and kill yourself with a system call per field? Even with proper serialization, per-field write/read is insane.

Comment: @SergeyA What, you've never heard of buffered I/O?

Comment: You could just put a signature at the end of the structure and verify it at runtime. Perhaps just for debug builds, and put it into your unit tests.

Comment: @SteveSummit, problem with buffered IO is that it can only support a very limited number of devices you can be writing to (files namely). Sockets/pipes/who knows what is off limit.

Comment: @SteveSummit, you're right... funny, I remember doing something similar with structs, but I think I got my memory mixed up... :-p

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry, didn't notice the C++ tag, I was thinking C.  In C I'd use `fdopen`.  But in any case, you can also use straightforward de/serialization techniques to un/pack your structs from/to a buffer of unsigned char, and then use that as your network packet or whatever. (But we're getting off track, because the OP *was* asking about disk files.)

Comment: @SergeyA Anyway, insanity is in the eye of the beholder.  Me, I think it's insane (and often impossible) to try to teach your compiler to exactly match the sizes, endiannesses, and padding (or lack thereof) of your external formats.  (And this question demonstrates the insanity well.  Even if the in-memory struct can somehow be matched to the on-disk format in all cases, the in-memory format might end up being significantly inefficient for processing in some environments.)

Comment: Apparently "good reason" isn't sufficient on SO.  :-)  Added additional comment: It's a memory-mapped file accessed randomly through pointers.  Serialization isn't an option.

Comment: Don't see why the `C` tag was removed.  My program is C++ but anything that worked in C should work there also.

Comment: @BrianWhite Sorry -- I did see your words "good reason", but I didn't imagine you were doing memory-mapped I/O!  Indeed that rather changes things.  Sorry for lecturing you about serialization.  (And good luck if any of those pointers are ever stored in the structs themselves... :-) )

Comment: Serialization *is* an option, you just serialize to/from a fixed size byte buffer instead of directly to the file.

Comment: @MarkRansom, serialization is **not** an option in my use-case.  Take my word for it.

Comment: OK, if you insist. The simplest solution would be to calculate the size of the struct and use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to make sure it matches. This has the added benefit of warning you if you make changes to the struct that render it incompatible with earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the closest thing to "automatic" that I could come up with:*

For all structures that are going to be used within this persistent binary data, add an attribute with the expected instance size.

```
struct MyPersistentBinaryStructure {
  // Expected size for 32/64-bit check.
  static constexpr size_t kExpectedInstanceSize = 80;

  ... 80 bytes of fixed size fields and appropriate padding ...
};
```

Then, in the code that looks up the address of structures within that binary data, check that value:

```
template <typename T>
T* GetAsObject(Reference ref) {
  static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "only simple objects");
  static_assert(T::kExpectedInstanceSize == sizeof(T), "inconsistent size");
  return reinterpret_cast<T*>(GetPointerFromRef(ref));
}
```

Any build that compiles the structure to a different size will give a compile-time error.  This doesn't future-proof the build because a definition that would be different for width X won't get caught until it is actually built on an architecture of width X, but at least you'll know and maybe be able to adapt the structure without breaking the format (e.g. 32-bit `int` -> `int32_t`).

Doing this turned out to be worth the effort as it immediately found three 32/64 incompatibilities within code that I'd manually checked with significant care.  Two of those errors would have caused data corruption; the other was just some extra tail padding.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a hack than an answer, but I do believe you could use something like this (which will make things clearer for any future maintainer as well):

```
#include <limits.h>
#if ULONG_MAX == (0xffffffffffffffffUL) // 64 bit code here
// ...
#elif ULONG_MAX == (0xffffffffUL)  // 32 bit code here
// ...
#else
#error unsupported
#endif
```

P.S.

Having said that... I would avoid directly using structs when writing to files.

There's too much that can go wrong, and that's in addition to file bloating (the structs are padded, meaning you'll get a lot of arbitrary junk data in the files).

Better to use a serialization function that stores and loads each field separately and does so byte by byte (or bit by bit), avoiding such issues as 32/64 bits and endianess.

**EDIT**:

I saw the comments about using a mapped file for IO... kinda reminiscent of a database implementation.

In this case, I would probably settle for an explicit comment in the code for the struct and have all fields (where possible) be either bit-size explicit or unions. i.e.:

```
// this type is defined to make sure pointer sizes are the same for
// 64bit and 32bit systems.
typedef union {
  void *ptr;
  char _space[8];
} pntr_field;

struct {
  size_t length : 32; // explicit bit count for 64bit and 32bit compatibility
  size_t number : 32;
  pntr_field my_ptr;  // side-note: I would avoid pointers,
  size_t offset : 32; // side-note: offsets are better for persistence.
} my_struct;
```

However... even in this situation, assuming the file is expected to be transferrable across systems, I would probably use getter / setter functions with "root" offset style pointers.

This would allow both for the data to be compressed (avoid struct padding concerns) and allow for the ever-changing memory address of the mapped file (since every program restart, all the pointers will become invalid and what we really care about will be the offset of the data relative to the root of the file or the object)...

Good Luck!

Comment: Yup, that's the better way to do conditional compilation based on type sizes (if you must)!

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for correcting me before. And I agree that it's better to avoid writing the struct directly to a file - so many things can go wrong, not to mention that space is wasted.

Comment: As I said, the binary structure has to be able to be passed unchanged between 32 and 64 bit versions so it's not about conditional compilation.  Anyone with enough presence of mind to write that can accomplish the same by using fixed-size types and ensuring that they add up to the alignment of the next field.

Comment: @BrianWhite  - just put the same code in both sections, if you need it to work as you describe. The `if` statements simply make sure that future maintainers know what they're doing. Personally, I would probably put in the serialization functions in there and avoid a matching struct. You do know that different compilers might pad your structs differently, even on the same system. Why insist on a matching byte size?